# Cannot take a screenshot using puppeteer, it dumps an empty image file

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am having a skeleton html file named `test.html`, and here is what it contains:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

then I have another file aimed at opening the above file in chrome headless, add an image into it and then takes it screenshot, have a look:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('file://test.html')
  await page.$eval('body', (body) => {
    const imgElement = new window.Image()
    imgElement.src = 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10379601/29446482-04f7036a-841f-11e7-9872-91d1fc2ea683.png'
    body.appendChild(imgElement)
  })
  await page.waitForSelector('img')
  fs.writeFileSync('output.html', await page.content())
  await page.screenshot({
    path: 'screenshot.jpg'
  })
  await browser.close()
})()
```

upon running this code, I get an empty image file as screenshot. You can also note that I am dumping the contents of the page using:

`fs.writeFileSync('output.html', await page.content())`

Opening `output.html` in my browser contains the image I was expecting in the screenshot. Why is the screenshot generated empty then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to that you didn't wait for the image to download. You are waiting only for `await page.waitForSelector('img')` but this one wait's for DOM element, not the actual image. It is a race condition between image download and taking a screenshot. 
You should wait for image `onload` like this:

```
await page.$eval('body', async (body) => {
    const imgElement = new window.Image()
    imgElement.src = 'https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10379601/29446482-04f7036a-841f-11e7-9872-91d1fc2ea683.png'
    body.appendChild(imgElement)

    await new Promise(resolve => {
        imgElement.onload = resolve;
    });
});
```